# Change transition type depending on screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically what code should do - if website size is greater than 750 px then dropdown slides down with hover effect, but if its less than 750 px dropdown works on click toggle.

I check if media query has changed with (greater than 750px float == left) and if (less than 750 px float == none)
It works onclick toggle if i start with 650 px web width, but when i resize it to full screen and then go back to 650 px, it shows as hover and as onclick toggle not only on click toggle.

Anyone can explain what i am doing wrong? I am quite new to jquery.

Thanks in advance!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    checkSize();
    $(window).resize(checkSize);
});

//Function to the css rule
function checkSize() {
    if ($("#drop > li").css("float") == "none") {
        $('#dropdown-btn').click(function() {
            $('.dropdown').slideToggle(200);

        });
    } else if ($("#drop > li").css("float") == "left") {
        $('#dropdown-btn').hover(
            function() {
                $('.dropdown').slideDown(200);




            },
            function() {
                $('.dropdown').slideUp(200);


            }

        );
    }
};
```

Comment: I think I'd restructure to call `checkSize()` on click, then take the appropriate menu action. As it is, you're creating new click functions multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the fact, that your checkSize function binds an event every single time it triggers, which is quite a lot on resize. A better way is to get rid of your resize function and use the if statement right in your event like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#dropdown-btn').on('click',function() {
      if($("#drop > li").css("float") == "none"))
        $('.dropdown').slideToggle(200);
    });

    $('#dropdown-btn').on({
      mouseenter: function () {
        //stuff to do on mouse enter
        if ($("#drop > li").css("float") == "left")
          $('.dropdown').slideDown(200);
      },
      mouseleave: function () {
        //stuff to do on mouse leave
        if ($("#drop > li").css("float") == "left")
          $('.dropdown').slideUp(200);
      }
});
```

You should also use jQuerys `on()` function instead of `hover()` or `click()`.

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: `$.click(handler)`is a shorthand for `$.on('click', handler)`.

Comment: Thats true and its not a must at all. Anyway its a better practice to use `on` over `click` for several reasons. Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click